# Error when trying to use an account in Benchmarks expected associated type, found enum `RawOrigin`

Tags: benchmarking, benchmark

I have the following account initialisation on benchmarking.rs file. The following configuration works on mock.rs and test.rs files but getting errors in benchmarking

```
pub(crate) fn test_pub(n: u8) -> sp_core::sr25519::Public {
    sp_core::sr25519::Public::from_raw([n; 32])
}
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Hash))]
pub struct AccountId(pub u64);

impl sp_std::fmt::Display for AccountId {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut sp_std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> sp_std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

impl From<u64> for AccountId {
    fn from(account_id: u64) -> Self {
        Self(account_id)
    }
}
```

benchmarking.rs file as follows

```
//! Benchmarks for Template Pallet
#![cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]

#![allow(unused_imports)]
use super::*;

use crate::Pallet as Sample;
use frame_benchmarking::{account, benchmarks, whitelisted_caller};
use frame_system::{self, RawOrigin, Origin};
use sp_runtime::traits::StaticLookup;
use pallet_primitives::DataDTO;
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

fn initial_setup <T: Config + pallet_marks::Config + pallet_admin::Config>(caller: T::AccountId) {
 let account_id = T::Lookup::unlookup(caller.clone());
}
const SEED: u32 = 0;

fn assert_last_event<T: Config>(generic_event: <T as Config>::Event) {
    frame_system::Pallet::<T>::assert_last_event(generic_event.into());
}

pub(crate) fn test_pub(n: u8) -> sp_core::sr25519::Public {
    sp_core::sr25519::Public::from_raw([n; 32])
}
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Hash))]
pub struct AccountId(pub u64);

impl sp_std::fmt::Display for AccountId {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut sp_std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> sp_std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

impl From<u64> for AccountId {
    fn from(account_id: u64) -> Self {
        Self(account_id)
    }
}
benchmarks!{
  create_marks {

        let data: dataDTO  = DataDTO {
            version: 1_u32,
            active: false,
        };
        let acc = test_pub(1);
        pallet_marks::Pallet::<T>::register_marks(
            Origin::Signed(acc.clone())
        );
         


  }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(acc.clone()), data)
 verify {
    let mark_id = 1u32;
    assert_last_event::<T>(Event::<T>::Created(mark_id, acc).into());
 }
 impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
  Sample,
  crate::mock::new_test_ext(),
  crate::mock::Test)
}
```

When I try to run this I am getting the following error

```
|             Origin::Signed(acc.clone())
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found enum `RawOrigin`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::Origin`
                         found enum `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::Origin` to `RawOrigin<sp_core::sr25519::Public>` or calling a method that returns `<T as frame_system::Config>::Origin`
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you try adding `.into()`?